# NEXT JS reloads page and redirect user to home page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next-router

My user is in `www.domain.com/product/details` page and when it click on reload page button on the browser. [image: This reload button]

The NEXT JS app reloads and redirect user to the home page with `www.domain.com/`. is there any way that when ever user reload or refresh the app reloads but the user stay on the same page as it was on before refreshing. I do not want to add any 'refresh' button on my app.

I want the app to reload as normal but user should stay on the same page when app is fully loaded. Like for example on `amazon.com` when I am on a product's page `amazon.com/product/details` and I click on refresh page on browser's tab, the page reloads and I am still on the same page `amazon.com/product/details`.

Comment: Please do provide the code of the page  /product/details

Comment: It is possible but you should configure it on level of server, like ngnix, firebase or netilfy hosting, because by default next router should handle this problem correctly. Can you add more description, how you deployed this app with server config?

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for response, I am using Netlify Hosting.

Comment: HI. Have you found any solution?